# Multiprocessing to return large data sets in Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have 2 functions in a Python 3.7 script that search 2 separate network nodes and returns very large data sets of strings in a list.  The smaller data set length is ~300K entries, while the larger one is ~1.5M.  This script takes almost an hour to execute because of how it has to compile the data sets as well as having the second data set be significantly larger.  I don't have a way to shorten the run time by changing how the compilation happens, there's no easier way for me to get the data from the network nodes.  But I can cut almost 10 minutes if I can run them simultaneously, so I'm trying to shorten the run time by using multiprocessing so I can run both of them at once.

I do not need them to necessarily start within the same second or finish at the same second, just want them to run at the same time.

Here's a breakdown of first attempt at coding for multiprocessing:

```
def p_func(arg1, arg2, pval):
     ## Do Stuff
    return pval

def s_func(arg1, sval):
    ## Do Stuff
    return sval

# Creating variables to get return values that multiprocessing can handle
pval = multiprocessing.Value(list)
sval = multiprocessing.Value(list)

# setting up multiprocessing Processes for each function and passing arguments
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=p_func, args=(arg1, arg2, pval))
s2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=s_func, args=(arg3, sval))
p1.start()
s1.start()
p1.join()
s1.join()

print("Number of values in pval: ", len(pval))
print("Number of values in sval: ", len(sval))
```

I believe I have solved my `list` concerns, so....

Based on comments I've updated my code as follows:

```
#! python3
import multiprocessing as mp
def p_func(arg1, arg2, pval):
    # takes arg1 and arg2 and queries network node to return list of ~300K
    # values and assigns that list to pval for return to main()
    return pval

def s_func(arg1, sval):
    # takes arg1 and queries network node to return list of ~1.5M 
    # values and assigns that list to sval for return to main()
    return sval

# Creating variables to get return values that multiprocessing can handle in 
# main()
with mp.Manager() as mgr
    pval = mgr.list()
    sval = mgr.list()

    # setting up multiprocessing Processes for each function and passing 
    # arguments
    p1 = mp.Process(target=p_func, args=(arg1, arg2, pval))
    s1 = mp.Process(target=s_func, args=(arg3, sval))
    p1.start()
    s1.start()
    p1.join()
    s1.join()

# out of with block
print("Number of values in pval: ", len(pval))
print("Number of values in sval: ", len(sval))
```

Now getting a **TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects** on the `p1.start()` invocation.  I'm guessing that one of the variables I have passed in the `p1` declaration is causing a problem with multiprocessing, but I'm not sure how to read the error or resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Manager.list()` instead:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def p_func(pval):
    pval.extend(list(range(300000)))

def s_func(sval):
    sval.extend(list(range(1500000)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Creating variables to get return values that mp can handle
    with mp.Manager() as mgr:
        pval = mgr.list()
        sval = mgr.list()

        # setting up mp Processes for each function and passing arguments
        p1 = mp.Process(target=p_func, args=(pval,))
        s2 = mp.Process(target=s_func, args=(sval,))
        p1.start()
        s2.start()
        p1.join()
        s2.join()

        print("Number of values in pval: ", len(pval))
        print("Number of values in sval: ", len(sval))
```

Output:

```
Number of values in pval:  300000
Number of values in sval:  1500000
```

`Manager` objects are slower than shared memory but more flexible.  Shared memory is faster, so if you know an upper limit for your arrays, you could use a fixed-sized shared memory `Array` and a shared value indicating the used size instead, such as:

```
#!python3
import multiprocessing as mp

def p_func(parr,psize):
    for i in range(10):
        parr[i] = i
    psize.value = 10

def s_func(sarr,ssize):
    for i in range(5):
        sarr[i] = i
    ssize.value = 5

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Creating variables to get return values that mp can handle
    parr = mp.Array('i',2<<20) # 2M
    sarr = mp.Array('i',2<<20)
    psize = mp.Value('i',0)
    ssize = mp.Value('i',0)

    # setting up mp Processes for each function and passing arguments
    p1 = mp.Process(target=p_func, args=(parr,psize))
    s2 = mp.Process(target=s_func, args=(sarr,ssize))
    p1.start()
    s2.start()
    p1.join()
    s2.join()

    print("parr: ", parr[:psize.value])
    print("sarr: ", sarr[:ssize.value])
```

Output:

```
parr:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
sarr:  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I like this solution and I'm going to try it, but I have a concern about setting a hard size for the data sets.  Is there any way to ensure that, if I have to use Array, that I can have that array dynamically sized, so I'm not facing the possibility of missing output? The data sets I'm pulling from could be vastly larger or smaller than what I've described in the problem, based on network conditions.

Comment: @GrandMasterD Then use the `Manager.list()` solution.  It is dynamic and more like the Python `list`.  `Array` is fixed-size.